# Hadoop: Processing different files with different Mappers and combining results in Reducer using Custom Writable

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am learning Hadoop.
I have 2 Mappers both processing different files and 1 Reducer combining inputs from both Mappers.

Input:
File 1:

```
1,Abc
2,Mno
3,Xyz
```

File 2:

```
1,CS
2,EE
3,CS
```

Expected output:

```
1   1,Abc,CS
2   2,Mno,EE
3   3,Xyz,CS
```

Getting Output:

```
1   1,,CS
2   2,Mno,
3   3,Xyz,
```

My Code:

Mapper 1:

```
public class NameMapper extends MapReduceBase implements
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, UserWritable> {

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
            OutputCollector<LongWritable, UserWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {

        String val[] = value.toString().split(",");

        LongWritable id = new LongWritable(Long.parseLong(val[0]));
        Text name = new Text(val[1]);

        output.collect(id, new UserWritable(id, name, new Text("")));
    }
}
```

Mapper2:

```
public class DepartmentMapper extends MapReduceBase implements
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, UserWritable> {

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
            OutputCollector<LongWritable, UserWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {

        String val[] = value.toString().split(",");

        LongWritable id = new LongWritable(Integer.parseInt(val[0]));
        Text department = new Text(val[1]);

        output.collect(id, new UserWritable(id, new Text(""), department));
    }
}
```

Reducer:

```
public class JoinReducer extends MapReduceBase implements
        Reducer<LongWritable, UserWritable, LongWritable, UserWritable> {

    @Override
    public void reduce(LongWritable key, Iterator<UserWritable> values,
            OutputCollector<LongWritable, UserWritable> output,
            Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

        UserWritable user = new UserWritable();

        while (values.hasNext()) {

            UserWritable u = values.next();

            user.setId(u.getId());

            if (!(u.getName().equals(""))) {
                user.setName(u.getName());
            }

            if (!(u.getDepartment().equals(""))) {
                user.setDepartment(u.getDepartment());
            }
        }
        output.collect(user.getId(), user);
    }
}
```

Driver:

```
public class Driver extends Configured implements Tool {

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JobConf conf = new JobConf(getConf(), Driver.class);
        conf.setJobName("File Join");

        conf.setOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(UserWritable.class);

        conf.setReducerClass(JoinReducer.class);

        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(conf, new Path("/user/hadoop/join/f1"),
                TextInputFormat.class, NameMapper.class);

        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(conf, new Path("/user/hadoop/join/f2"),
                TextInputFormat.class, DepartmentMapper.class);

        Path output = new Path("/user/hadoop/join/output");
        FileSystem.get(new URI(output.toString()), conf).delete(output);

        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, output);

        JobClient.runJob(conf);

        return 0;
    }

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         int result = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new Driver(), args);
         System.exit(result);
     }
}
```

UserWritable:

```
public class UserWritable implements Writable {

    private LongWritable id;
    private Text name;
    private Text department;

    public UserWritable() {
    }

    public UserWritable(LongWritable id, Text name, Text department) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.department = department;
    }

    public LongWritable getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(LongWritable id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Text getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(Text name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Text getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Text department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        id = new LongWritable(in.readLong());
        name = new Text(in.readUTF());
        department = new Text(in.readUTF());
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeLong(id.get());
        out.writeUTF(name.toString());
        out.writeUTF(department.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id.get() + "," + name.toString() + "," + department.toString();
    }
}
```

Reducer should get 2 UserWritable objects for every UserId; 1st having id,name and 2nd having id,department.
Can anyone explain where I made mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in my code.

```
u.getName()
```

return Text object.

`u.getName().toString()` resolved problem.